# Why Captured images are not showing up in Samsung S21 (Android 11)

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-gallery

In our app, There is a  camera photo capture feature and its capture images successfully and saved in External storage(/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Appname/foldername). But its not showing up in Gallery.

Code we use to save the captured images;

```
   private void  saveToPublicStorage(Bitmap bitmap,File file) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            out = getFOSForPublicCameraDirectory(file.getName());
        } else {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        }
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        ExceptionLogger.logException(e);
    }




private FileOutputStream getFOSForPublicCameraDirectory(String fileName) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri imageUri = getURIForPublicCameraDirectory(fileName);
        try {
            fos = (FileOutputStream) contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionLogger.logException(e);
        }
        return fos;
    }



private Uri getURIForPublicCameraDirectory(String fileName) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + "Camera" + File.separator + "Folder1" + File.separator + "Folder2");
        return contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    }
```

Also this same piece of code working in Samsung S20(Android 11).The problem is only with S20.
I have followed https://www.samsung.com/us/support/troubleshooting/TSG01001310/ and checked all the given scenarios and nothing helped.

Comment: `its capture images successfully and saved in "My Files" app. ` One cannot store images in apps. Images are saved to a storage location. Please rephrase.

Comment: @blackapps Images are stored in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Appname/foldername

Comment: You should let the media store scanner scan every new picture.

Comment: yeah! But I want to understand how the same piece of code working in S20 and not in S21. Do you have any idea on this?